# Set focus on a newly opened browser using webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver, ui-automation

I am using ruby and watir-webdriver for automating a web application where I came across the scenario where a new browser is opened when I click on a button and I've to fill a form on the newly opened window. Webdriver is unable to identify it as a window.

Is there anyway for handling this scenario? As I know, We can't connect to a browser instance which is not started by webdriver.

I used the below code to check if the window exists

```
@browser.window(:title => /#{title}/i).wait_until_present
```

I also tried below code to check all the opened windows but the new browser instance was not coming in the list

```
@browser.windows.each { |w| p w.title}
```

Comment: Have you tried something along the lines of:  `driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());`?  This may not be the correct syntax for `Ruby` but, it should be relatively close.

Comment: Are you sure it is actually a browser window? Is it possible that it is just an element on the page that is meant to look like a popup? For example, the [jQueryUI dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) looks like a window, but is just an element in the original browser window (ie not a new window).

Comment: @brian -> I've done similar thing in ruby but as I said, the problem is it is not a child window, it is a new browser session.

Comment: @justin -> yeah I'm sure it is a new browser not a pop-up thing.

Comment: 1. Could you provide an example of the page? HTML or similar page in the Internet? It will be much easier to suggest something when it will be possible to play around with your situation.
2. I never ever allow watir-webdriver to open new tabs. Usually I am modifying the link to open it at the same page. That's a dirty workaround but it helps.

Comment: @Antesser -> how do you do that ? and sorry I don't have anything on internet which may work in this manner

Comment: It depends. If it's a link like <a href='lol' id='new_tab' target='_blank'>link </a> it is enough to do something like browser.execute_script("arguments[0].target = ''", browser.element(:id, 'new_tab')) More complex situations must be resolved by javascript modifying. That's why it will be much better if you will provide the HTML code of your page or example.

Comment: I looked into the HTML code and they all are custom built functions. And I was unable to get inside code of the function that was creating the window.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [`Watir::Window#use`](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/blob/93bd1270cdfb650c2029b4d2295dc4d0e785b665/lib/watir-webdriver/window.rb#L191) was developed for this exact use case. It switches to a different window, performs an action (passed as a code block), and then switches back to the original window. For example:

```
@browser.window(title: /#{title}/i).use do
  # Whatever you need to do on the new window, like:
  @browser.text_field(id: "some-id").set "Foo"
  @browser.button(id: "submit").click
end
```

Comment: as I said.. it is not a child window... it is a new browser session